# Perl: Negative look behind regex

Tags: perl, regex

The [Perlre in Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) didn't go into much detail on negative look around but I tried testing it, and didn't work as expected.  I want to see if I can differentiate a C preprocessor macro definition (e.g. #define MAX(X) ....) from actual usage (y = MAX(x);), but it didn't work as expected.

```
my $macroName = 'MAX';
my $macroCall = "y = MAX(X);";
my $macroDef  = "# define MAX(X)";

my $boundary = qr{\b$macroName\b};
my $bstr     = "  MAX(X)";

if ( $bstr =~ /$boundary/ ) {
    print "boundary: $bstr matches: $boundary\n";
} else {
    print "Error: no match: boundary: $bstr, $boundary\n";
}

my $negLookBehind = qr{(?<!define)\b$macroName\b};

if ( $macroCall =~ /$negLookBehind/ ) {   # "y = MAX(X)" matches "(?<!define)\bMAX\b"
    print "negative look behind: $macroCall matches: $negLookBehind\n";
} else {
    print "no match: negative look behind: $macroCall, $negLookBehind\n";
}

if ( $macroDef =~ /$negLookBehind/ ) {   # "#define MAX(X)" should not match "(?<!define)\bMAX\b"
    print "Error: negative look behind: $macroDef matches: $negLookBehind\n";
} else {
    print "no match: negative look behind: $macroDef, $negLookBehind\n";
}
```

It seems that both `$macroDef` and `$macroCall` seem to match regex `/(?<!define)\b$macroName\b/`.  I backed off from the original `/(?<\#)\s*(?<!define)\b$macroName\b/` since that didn't work either.  So what did I screw up?  Also does Perl allow chaining of multiple look around expressions?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a space after `define` in `(?<!define)`.   Fixed:

```
my $negLookBehind = qr{(?<!define )\b$macroName\b};
```

Please note:  Positive and Negative lookbehind assertions are required to be fixed width.  If this were not the case, then their usage would lead to exponential growth in matching times.  (The only exception to this is the special `\K` escape code)

For an additional reference: [perlretut - Looking ahead and looking behind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)

As for your other question: "*does Perl allow chaining of multiple look around expressions?*".  The answer is, Yes.